# how to code in coq a function that sum the integers represented by the 2 lists and boolean representing a holdback?

Tags: coq, proof

I want to set the recursive function badd_r: list bool -> list bool -> bool -> list bool that sum the integers represented by the 2 lists and boolean representing a holdback.
I need to use these two functions b1add_r(sum of two lists), bsucc(successor of a binary number represented by a list of booleans).
Here are the two functions:

```
Fixpoint bsucc (l: list bool):  list bool :=
  match l with
  | []  =>[true]
  | true::r => false:: (bsucc r)
  | false::r => true::r
end.

Definition b1add_r b1 b2 r :=
  match b1,b2 with
    true, true => (r,true)
  | true,false => (negb r, r)
  | false, true => (negb r,r)
  | false,false => (r, false)
end.
```

I have no idea how to code this function in coq and how to prove it...

```
Lemma badd_rOK: forall l1 l2 r,
  value (badd_r l1 l2 r) = value l1 + value l2 + (if r then 1 else 0).

Fixpoint value (l: list bool) :=
  match l with
  | [] => 0
  | true :: r => 1 + 2 * value r
  | false :: r => 2 * value r
end.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with some other functional language like ocaml, haskell or lisp?  If you know how you would program it in another language it is not that difficult to translate to Coq's language.  Notice that b1add_r is a [full adder](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/full%20adder#/Full_adder) so it just adds two bits and a "memory digit" and returns the next "memory digit" and the next bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your function may have the following form:

```
Fixpoint badd_r (l1 l2:list bool) (r : bool) : list bool :=
  match l1, l2 with
    nil, nil => (* base case 1 *)
  | a::r1, nil => (* base case 2 *)
  | nil, b::r2 => (* base case 3 *)
  | a::r1, b:: r2 => let (c, r') := b1add_r a b r
                     in (* recursive case *)
  end.
```

In order to fill the holes/comments, and plan to prove correctness, you may relate arithmetic properties with the possible cases.
For instance, the equality `(1+2*x)+(0+2*y)+1= 0+2(x+y+1)` corresponds to the case `add_r (true::r) (false::s) true = false :: (add_r r s true)`

Comment: I am sorry I don't really understand what I should put in the blank...Is it something like this : ```Fixpoint badd_r (l1 l2:list bool) (r : bool) : list bool :=
  match l1, l2 with
    nil, nil => nil
  | a::r1, nil => b1add_r a::r1 nil r
  | nil, b::r2 => b1add_r nil b::r2 r
  | a::r1, b:: r2 => let (c, r') := b1add_r a b r
                     in (* recursive case *)
end. ```

Comment: No, in the first case, when both lists are nil, you are essentially adding zero + zero + r,  and you should return a list with r.  In the second case you are adding zero + l2 + r, so if r is false you should return l2, and if r is true you should return l2 + 1, i..e the successor of l2, i.e bsucc l2. And so on...

Comment: what about the others cases? Sorry I don't get the logic

Comment: here what I understood so far : ```Fixpoint badd_r (l1 l2:list bool) (r : bool) : list bool :=
  match l1, l2 with
    nil, nil => [r]
  | a::r1, nil => if r = [false] then a::r1 else bsucc a::r1
  | nil, b::r2 => if r = [false] then b::r2 else bsucc b::r2
  | a::r1, b:: r2 => let (c, r') := b1add_r a b r
                     in b1add_r a b r
end.```